# 'Source' output of a command in bash script as multiple variables

Tags: bash, awk

I have MSI file, which have inside version.ini file which contains multiple variables I need to take out.

For example:

```
[VERSION]
fileid=...
version=...
option=...
```

So I have simple command:

```
cabextract -p -F "version.ini" installer.msi | awk -F '=' '{if ($1 == "fileid" || $1 == "version" || $1 == "language") print tolower($1)"=\""$2"\"";}' > /tmp/tmpoutput
source /tmp/tmpoutput
echo $version
```

and with that I achieved extracting version.ini from a msi file and extracting from ini file information I want.

But just for curiosity is there any prettier version to take out variables without temporary writing it to a file.
It has nosense, but I cannot find another working and simple way to load multiple variables.

If I write command like that:

```
var=$(cabextract -p -F "version.ini" installer.msi | awk -F '=' '{if ($1 == "fileid" || $1 == "version" || $1 == "language") printtolower($1)"=\""$2"\"";}')
```

it won't work.
I can't put command in `$()` because then it merge results of awk command.
I've tried to put it into array but that also failed.

Any advice?

Comment: You can just use `eval` here: `eval "$(cabextract ...)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`process substitution`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) here:

```
source <(cabextract -p -F "version.ini" installer.msi | awk -F '=' '{if ($1 == "fileid" || $1 == "version" || $1 == "language") print tolower($1)"=\""$2"\"";}')
```

Using this directive output of `cabextract` will be used for `source` like a file.

Comment: thanks a lot! I've tried that before but won't work. When somebody else posted it, I checked and I started my script with /bin/sh so bash was trying to be sh and process substitution won't work.

Comment: A more portable (and efficient) option is to use `eval`…